# FPDF FPDF error: Missing or incorrect image file

Tags: php, fpdf

I have seen all the posts about this but none have helped me. I have turned on the `allow_URL_fopen` and `allow_url_include`. no go

Tried to play with the url adding `http://` and doing absolute path still no go.

Tried to do only `/images`

If I include the full path it will work.

```
$pdf->Image('http://vsag.actualizevps.com/process/upload/8/cdv_photo_001.jpg',null,null,55,0,'jpg');
```

the problem is that im pulling the links from DB 
when i pull it it will throw following error -

```
Warning: getimagesize(vsag.actualizevps.com/process/upload/8/cdv_photo_001.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /public_html/fpdf/fpdf.php on line 1213 
FPDF error: Missing or incorrect image file: vsag.actualizevps.com/process/upload/8/cdv_photo_001.jpg
```

That file does exist - `vsag.actualizevps.com/process/upload/8/cdv_photo_001.jpg`

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$yn = $row['answer_2'];
$grade = $row['answer_3'];
$answer = $row['answer_1'];
$pict = $row['image_1'];
if (empty($row['image_1']))
{$image1="vsag.actualizevps.com/process/upload/camera.jpg";}
else {$image1 = "vsag.actualizevps.com/process/upload/$pict";}


//$image1 = "http://vsag.actualizevps.com/process/upload/"$row['image_1'];
//$image1 = "http://vsag.actualizevps.com/process/upload/".$imageadd;
if($yn=='' ){$yn = "N/A";}
$pdf->Cell(0,10,$row['question_text'],0,1);
$pdf->Cell(0,10,'Answer - '.$answer,0,1);
$pdf->Cell(0,10,'YES/NO - '.$yn,0,1);
$pdf->Cell(0,10,'Grade - '.$grade,0,1);
//$pdf->Image($image1,null,null,55,0,'jpg');
$pdf->Cell(0,0,$pdf->Image($image1,$xaxis,$yaxis,25,29),0,0,'L',0);
//$pdf-  >Image('http://vsag.actualizevps.com/process/upload/8/cdv_photo_001.jpg',null,null,55,0,'jpg');
//$pdf->Image('http://vsag.actualizevps.com/process/upload/8/cdv_photo_002.jpg',null,null,55,0,'jpg');
//$pdf->Image('http://vsag.actualizevps.com/process/upload/8/cdv_photo_003.jpg',null,null,55,0,'jpg');
//$pdf->Cell(0,10,$image1,1,0,1);
$pdf->Cell(0,10,'__________________________________________________________________________________________',0,1);
//$pdf->WriteHTML('<img src="http://vsag.actualizevps.com/models/site-    templates/images/vsag_header_logo.jpg">');
}
$pdf->Output();
```

Comment: And where are the images exactly? In `process/upload/` ?

Comment: make your code simpler

Comment: Images are - example - process/upload/8/cdv_photo_001.jpg